# The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location

Tags: c#, clickonce, outlook-addin

I got an The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location.

Settings that I am using :

1. Publish Location is local file path `D:\Test Applications\publish`
   And the instalation path is coming as `D:\Test Applications\publish\MdnOutlookPlugin.vsto` and installing fine.
2. After publishing again from visual studio it is trying to update but path is coming as different.

   file:///D:/Test Applications/mdn-outlook-plugin/MdnOutlookPlugin/bin/Release/MdnOutlookPlugin.vsto

Which is actually my project folder path. And I am getting following error.

```
Name:
```

From: file:///D:/Test Applications/mdn-outlook-plugin/MdnOutlookPlugin/bin/Release/MdnOutlookPlugin.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.AddInAlreadyInstalledException: The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location. To install this version of the customization, first use Add or Remove Programs to uninstall this program: MdnOutlookPlugin. Then install the new customization from the following location: file:///D:/Test Applications/mdn-outlook-plugin/MdnOutlookPlugin/bin/Release/MdnOutlookPlugin.vsto
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySolutionCodebaseIsUnchanged(Uri uri, String subscriptionId, Boolean previouslyInstalled)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Can you help .

Comment: Can any once help me to solve this  issue.

Comment: FYI I'm having the same issue. I've not yet found a way to properly resolve it though - it looks like under some circumstances VS runs `SetOffice2007AddinRegistration` on publish rather than on build + execute, which I believe configured Office to recognise your (debug) addin. No idea how to fix yet though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete a registry key located at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions\{GUID}
```

The value of {GUID} will be different in your environment.

Check to ensure that you're deleting the right key. Confirm by checking the `DWORD` "Url" value at the key.

Read more about this issue in the following articles:

- [Fixing Deployment.AddInAlreadyInstalledException](https://censore.blogspot.com/2015/12/fixing-deploymentaddinalreadyinstallede.html)
- [VSTO: The Customization Cannot Be Installed](https://charliedigital.com/2010/12/03/vsto-the-customization-cannot-be-installed/)
- [AddInAlreadyInstalledException](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f15ad3fc-4ab0-4825-b399-e9b860636eef/addinalreadyinstalledexception)